# Using a PIC12F675 to generate a PWM signal using Timer0 and Timer1 interrupts

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I would like to generate a PWM signal using Timer0 and Timer1 interrupts.
The reason for using Timer0 interrupt is adjusting the frequency and the reason for using Timer1 interrupt is a adjusting stop (off time).
I wrote the ISR for that in mikroC.
Can you help me?

```
void interrupt(){
  if(INTCON.T0IF){
    tmr0=122;
    tmr1l=122;
    tmr1h=0; //NOT USING TİMER1 H BİT
    INTCON.T0IF=0;
  }
  if(PIR1.TMR1IF){
  GPIO.B0=0;
  PIR1.TMR1IF=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really clear on what your question is. It does seem that you are missing a GPIO.B0=1; for starting the high active time of the PWM waveform.

Comment: You want to write a software PWM?